# Hyperboloid equation related question?

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

How to draw this graph please?

$$4y^2 -x^2+4z^2-1 \geq  0$$

Comment: The hyperboloid ($=0$) is the result of rotating $4 y^2 = 1 + x^2$ around the $x$-axis. So, carefully draw  $4 y^2 = 1 + x^2$ in the $x,y$ plane.

Comment: I just changed my question because it didnt make any sense to me..

Comment: Just a note, $\ge$ is "\ge" not "\gt="

Comment: Please draw the two-dimensional hyperbola I indicated.

Comment: how about z?    :/

Comment: @Beyonce90: Is this what you are looking for? It is plotted as a [*parametric plot*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parameteric+plot+4y%5E2+-+x%5E2+%2B4z%5E2+-+1+) using WA. Also, do you see how following Will Jagy's advice would have solved the problem?